# Collapsible column in Bulma

Tags: css, bulma

How would I collapse a Bulma column, like for a collapsible sidebar?

e.g.

```
<div class="columns">
  <div class="column" id="sidebar is-2">
  <div class="column" id="centre is-8">
  <div class="column" id="right is-2">
</div>
```

So that the left hand column closes up to is-0 and the remaining columns expland to take up the remaining space?